# How do I scale/resize a QGraphicsWidget based on the QGraphicScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicswidget

I would like my QGraphicsWidget to scale its size based on the size of the scene.  The QGraphicsWidget I have currently is a fixed size depending on the return value of sizeHint (QGraphicsWidget is always 200 x 200).  Attached below is minimal example:

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

#include "RectangleWidget.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene * m_scene;
    QGraphicsView * m_view;
    RectangleWidget * m_rectangleWidget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    m_view = new QGraphicsView(m_scene, this);
    m_view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    m_rectangleWidget = new RectangleWidget();

    m_scene->addItem(m_rectangleWidget);

    setCentralWidget(m_view);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

RectangleWidget.h:

```
#ifndef RECTANGLEWIDGET_H
#define RECTANGLEWIDGET_H

#include <QGraphicsLinearLayout>
#include <QGraphicsWidget>


class RectangleWidget: public QGraphicsWidget
{
public:
    RectangleWidget(QGraphicsWidget* parent = nullptr);

    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = nullptr) override;

    void setGeometry(const QRectF &geom) override;
    QSizeF sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which, const QSizeF &constraint = QSizeF()) const override;
};

#endif // RECTANGLEWIDGET_H
```

RectangleWidget.cpp:

```
#include "rectanglewidget.h"
#include <QPainter>

RectangleWidget::RectangleWidget(QGraphicsWidget* parent)
{

}

void RectangleWidget::paint(QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget /*= 0*/)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    Q_UNUSED(option);

    //Draw border
    painter->drawRoundedRect(boundingRect(), 0.0, 0.0);

}

QRectF RectangleWidget::boundingRect() const
{

    return QRectF(QPointF(0,0), geometry().size());
}

void RectangleWidget::setGeometry(const QRectF &geom)
{
    prepareGeometryChange();
    QGraphicsLayoutItem::setGeometry(geom);
    setPos(geom.topLeft());
}

QSizeF RectangleWidget::sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which, const QSizeF &constraint) const
{
    switch (which) {
    case Qt::MinimumSize:
        return QSizeF(200, 200);

    default:
        break;
    }
    return constraint;
}
```

[image: Window small]

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly should the size of the widget depend on the size of the scene? Should they be equal?

Comment: Any ratio is fine.  Let's just go ahead with 1/2 the size of the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background

Your *QGraphicsWidget* have to be aware of two things:

1. When it is added to a scene

In order to do that you have to reimplement `QGraphicsWidget::itemChange` and look for a change of type `QGraphicsItem::ItemSceneHasChanged`.

2. When the size of this scene changes

This could be done by connecting a slot or a lambda function to the `QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged` signal.

## Solution

Based on the given explanation, my solution would be the following:

In **RectangleWidget.h** after `QSizeF sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which, const QSizeF &constraint = QSizeF()) const override;` add:

```
protected:
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) override;

private:
    QSize m_rectSize;
```

In **RectangleWidget.cpp** change `return QSizeF(200, 200);` to `return m_rectSize;` and add at the end:

```
QVariant RectangleWidget::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == ItemSceneHasChanged) {
        connect(value.value<QGraphicsScene *>(), &QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged, [this](const QRectF &rect){
            m_rectSize.setWidth(rect.size().width());
            m_rectSize.setHeight(rect.size().height());
        });
    }

    return QGraphicsWidget::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Finally, in **MainWindow.cpp** after `m_scene->addItem(m_rectangleWidget);` set the `sceneRect` as follows:

```
m_scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 100, 400);
```

**Note:** The rectangle will respond to the changes of the scene, not the view. So if you resize the window, the rectangle will not be resized.

## Adjustment

This will make the rectangle exactly the same size as the scene. If you want a different ratio, say `0.5`, instead of `m_rectSize.setWidth(rect.size().width());` write `m_rectSize.setWidth(rect.size().width() / 2);`, respectively `m_rectSize.setHeight(rect.size().height() / 2);`.

Comment: I am now getting a fixed rectangle 50x200 now with your changes.  Are we missing something.  Can you send  the full 4 files?

Comment: Is there a way to connect the window size to the scene size?

Comment: @MichaelJapzon, there is. However, this is already another question and requires another solution. At best mark this one as solved and ask another one about the QGraphicsView.